# Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub

Tags: r, github, r-package

I'm having problems with my package on GitHub (https://github.com/igorcobelo/florestal). Until recently, it was working normally, I don't know what exactly happened. When I try to install it by:

```
remotes::install_github("igorcobelo/florestal")
```

The following error appears:

```
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 401.
  Bad credentials

  Rate limit remaining: 27/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2021-09-30 19:17:49 UTC
```

It looks like it's not being recognized as an R package, as if it's missing something. But it was working normally until recently, would anyone know the solution, please?

Comment: Sounds like you have an invalid personals access token (PAT) in your environment. What if you try `remotes::install_github("igorcobelo/florestal", auth_token = NULL)` to override? Or check out https://happygitwithr.com/credential-caching.html#credential-caching for possible ways to update your PAT (depending on how you set it in the first place)